# Call SQL file in the execute psycopg2 method?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I would like to know if it's possible to call a `sql` file with one single big query in a

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute( <bigQuery.sql> )
```

PS.: If I put the query in a `.py` file and make a constant will work. But that's not what I want to do. I want to call the `.sql` file directed in the `execute` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_file = open('/path/to/sql_statement.sql', 'r')
cursor.execute(sql_file.read())
```

Comment: warning: this code may not be memory/file safe as it doesn't use a context manager, or specify to close. When dealing with filestreams, you always want to open them in a `with` clause. See: https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/